# VHDL 2008 fixed and floating point type synthesis support?

Tags: vhdl

Which VHDL synthesis tools support the VHDL 2008 fixed and floating 
point types as described at [vhdl.org/fphdl](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/)? The
VHDL.org site states "all these packages are designed to be synthesizable in
VHDL-93".  Which tools have yield successful results synthesizing the 
VHDL-2008 fixed-point and floating-point types?

Second question, what is the status of VHDL-2008.  Has it been ratified?

Comment: Since the answer to the first question is likely to change over time, expect this to be closed.

Comment: Suggestions on a more appropriate way to state the question?  Or is it not a question suitable for this format?  Or simply ask, which tools in 2011 support ... ?

Comment: @Christoper Felton: I like the first part of the question. Perhaps this would be a good fit for a Community Wiki?

Comment: @Brian - It's perfectly legitimate to talk about standards compliance.  What we want to avoid is information which will only be *useful* for a specific time period. It's unlikely that implementors will drop their support for VHDL-2008, so I think this should stand.  This may need to be expanded in the future, but it's unlikely to become obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VHDL-2008 was ratified

> "In February 2008, Accellera approved VHDL 4.0 also informally known
>   as VHDL 2008, which addressed more than 90 issues discovered during
>   the trial period for version 3.0 and includes enhanced generic types.
>   In 2008, Accellera released VHDL 4.0 to the IEEE for balloting for
>   inclusion in IEEE 1076-2008. The VHDL standard IEEE 1076-2008 was
>   published in January 2009."

-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl

Comment: Thanks, so the standard has been set in stone for some time.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question *exactly*, but ANY working VHDL 93 synthesizer will work with fixed and floating point VHDL libraries under VHDL 93. To get these, see http://www.eda.org/fphdl/.

Comment: Link is broken - can't find the libraries elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I have used the VHDL fixed-point libraries in Altera's Quartus II (v9.1), with a Cyclone III. They synthesized an IIR filter and an LMS adaptive filter fairly efficiently - I noticed no major difference in resource usage compared to my previous implementation using numeric_std.

So, I am confident that Quartus supports the fixed-point libraries.

Comment: But you did have to use the IEEE_proposed libraries rather than the actual IEEE ones right?

Comment: That is correct, I used the IEEE_proposed libraries.